# How to run Gatsby website in a way that reproduces 404 error from live site?

Tags: localhost, gatsby, web-development-server, npm-run

I have a Gatsby site that throws a 404 error in Chrome devtools when run live. When I run it locally with `npm run develop`, I don't see the error. Is there a way to run the site locally in a way that mimics the live site so that I'm more likely to see the 404 error?

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```
gatsby build
```

And

```
gatsby serve
```

Summarizing, `gatsby build` will compile your application and make it ready for deployment while `gatsby serve` will serve the production build of your site for testing, by default at port `9000`.

More details about `gatsby-cli` commands at: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/gatsby-cli/